# LWC CLI Errors: Avoid long parameter lists (rule: Design-ExcessiveParameterList)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm working on LWC and I'm getting "Avoid long parameter lists (rule: Design-ExcessiveParameterList)" referring to this line of code in APEX:

```
  public static String addRemove(String userId, List <String> selectedQueues, List<String> updatedQueues,List <String> selectedPubGrps, List <string> updatedPubGrps,
  Boolean queuesUpdatedBool, Boolean pubGrpsUpdatedBool)
```

If someones has had something similar, could please explain what does this error is trying to say?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an ApexPMD *warning*, not an *error* (an error implies it won't be deployable to Salesforce, while a warning just means it's probably a Bad Idea™).

This specific warning means that you might have too many parameters, so you might consider restructuring your parameters so there's less of them.

Long parameter lists in Apex can make it hard to tell what parameters you're passing in which position, so it's generally considered a bad practice.

However, since you're calling this from LWC, it doesn't matter as much, because the parameters are placed into an Object with the properties matching the parameter names, so you can't accidentally place them out of order.

If you really wanted to avoid this warning, though, you could change your Apex:

```
public class Request {
    @AuraEnabled String userId { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled List <String> selectedQueues { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled List<String> updatedQueues { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled List <String> selectedPubGrps { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled List <string> updatedPubGrps { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled Boolean queuesUpdatedBool { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled Boolean pubGrpsUpdatedBoo { get; set; }
}
@AuraEnabled
public static String addRemove(Request parameters) {
```

This will clear up that particular warning, though you'll also need to change your LWC to match:

```
addRemove({ parameters: { userId: this.userId, ... }})
```

I'd probably do this in order to make the Apex code easier to test and maintain.

Comment: I try to follow Bob Martin's advice. If I need more than three params it might be time to think about making it an object.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson I myself try to keep under four, but I'll consider four parameters a possibility. At five parameters, though, I'm refactoring, period.

Comment: Honestly for me it's more like two.